# Canvas.drawRect is not work in TextView's onDraw when set gravity

Tags: android

I have a custom view extends form TextView,and write some code in onDraw():

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mTextShader == null) {
        createShader();
    }
    shaderMatrix.setTranslate(mProgressWidth,0);
    mTextShader.setLocalMatrix(shaderMatrix);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setShader(mBgShader);
    canvas.drawRect(0,0,mProgressWidth,getBottom(),paint);
    getPaint().setShader(mTextShader);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

It looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Bpa.jpg)
Just set some shader,and draw a rect,it works fine if I don't use

```
android:gravity="center"
```

and

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

together,(just one of them is pretty good,)

if only use this property,these shaders and rect are gone!

why?

Comment: because your Canvas is translated

Comment: @pskink And setGravity or setSingleLine will cause it not work?what should I do if I want draw a rect and use both of them?

Comment: either translate your Canvas back or change the points in your Rect

Comment: I can't get the point,can you be more simply and clearly

Comment: the Canvas is translated by getScrollX() pixels,  thats why you dont see your rect

Comment: see [here](http://pastebin.com/j6SpvUwd) for some working code

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your big help;

Answer (score 4):

Before you draw in the canvas, translate the scrolled XY distance

```java
canvas.translate(getScrollX(), getScrollY());
canvas.drawRect(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight(), borderPaint);
```

Answer (score 0):

your  super.onDraw(canvas); should be first line otherwise parent will paint on top of your drawing. also call this setWillNotDraw(false) in your constructor.

Comment: I guess TextView's  super.onDraw(canvas) will draw text after I draw a rect,so I put it last.

Comment: but have you checked does it only draw text or clear canvas before drawing ?